# MySQL SELECT Count of existence for each ID

Tags: mysql, sql, count, match

I have a table of images and I have another table of image tags.

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will get the number of valid tags per Image ID.

My initial attempt was this:

```
SELECT b.ID AS ID,  COUNT(a.ID) AS NUM
FROM tbl_tags a, tbl_images b 
WHERE (
    b.ID = a.IMG_ID AND 
      (a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%scenic%' OR 
       a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%fruit%' OR 
       a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bench%' OR 
       a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bird%'
      )
);
```

The result was this:

```
ID    NUM
7      13
```

However, what I want is to show the count value of tags for EACH Image ID found. What I'm looking for is something more like this:

```
ID    NUM
3      2     -- Image ID #3 has 2 tags that match the query
68     1     -- Image ID #68 has 1 tag that matches the query
87     3     -- ...
92     2     -- ...
187    1     -- ...
875    2     -- ...
```

Comment: You need `GROUP BY Id` at the end of your query.

Comment: can you please show your tables schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using `REGEXP` which cleans up the `WHERE` clause a bit:

```
SELECT
    a.ID,
    COUNT(b.ID) AS NUM
FROM tbl_images a
INNER JOIN tbl_tags b
    ON a.ID = b.IMG_ID
WHERE
    b.TAG_NAME REGEXP 'scenic|fruit|bench|bird'
GROUP BY
    a.ID;
```

Comment: I never knew you could use RegEx in SQL! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.IMG_ID,  COUNT(a.ID) AS NUM
FROM tbl_tags a
WHERE a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%scenic%' OR 
       a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%fruit%' OR 
       a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bench%' OR 
       a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bird%'      
Group by a.IMG_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Prefer the newer (since the 90's!) join syntax

   ```
   SELECT b.ID AS ID,  COUNT(a.ID) AS NUM
   FROM tbl_tags a
    INNER JOIN tbl_images b on b.ID = a.IMG_ID
   …
   ```

as it is much clearer.

2. To group when using aggregates use `GROUP BY`

   ```
   SELECT a.IMG_ID AS ID, COUNT(a.ID) AS NUM
   FROM tbl_tags a
   WHERE a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%scenic%' 
     OR a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%fruit%' 
     OR a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bench%'
     OR a.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bird%'
   GROUP BY a.IMG_ID
   ```

Note you don't really need the join here as you're not using anything from the `tbl_Images`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `join` at all for this, because the image id is in `tbl_tags`:

```
SELECT t.IMG_ID AS ID, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM tbl_tags t
WHERE t.TAG_NAME LIKE '%scenic%' OR 
      t.TAG_NAME LIKE '%fruit%' OR 
      t.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bench%' OR 
      t.TAG_NAME LIKE '%bird%'
GROUP BY t.img_id;
```

I strongly advise you to use abbreviations for table names (such as `t` for `tbl_tags`) rather than arbitrary letters.  It makes the query much easier to follow.